# When referring to filesystems, what is the difference between a "live" and a "dead" inode?

Tags: filesystems, inode

My understanding of 'inodes' (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) is that they contain the information necessary to access certain blocks of a file, but not the file data itself. Then I was wondering what the major differences between a live, and a dead, inode are.

I've heard the terms get swapped around often, but the only inference I can make is that perhaps dead inodes are ones that may be proceeded to be 'garbage collected'...

Thanks :)

Comment: "live" and "dead" are generally not associated with inodes.

Comment: Just curious, then, do you know the difference between inode arrays and imaps? Because I believe inode arrays just store a bunch of inodes, but I'm not sure if an imap is the same thing as an inode array...